# how to loop through a table in jquery and read span value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have grid view on asp.net page which is rendered in following format. I like to loop through the table and read control gvCart_ctl02_lblComboGroup value which is a span.

There will be number of rows and i want to loop through each row and read the span value from certain cell.

```html
<table id="gvCart">
   <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Product</th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>
         <div>
            <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblPromoPrice" style="font-weight:bold;">£187.62</span>
         </div>
         <div id="gvCart_ctl02_bundleQualifyForCombo">
            <div>
               <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboGroup" style="color:#E31837;font-size:2.5em;font-style:normal;">A</span>
            </div>
            <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboText" style="color:#0275C2;font-size:0.9em;font-style:normal;">5 Total From Group A Required</span>
         </div>
   </tr>


</table>
```

I have tried this but its not working;

```
var i = 1;
var t = document.getElementById('gvCart');

$("#gvCart tr").each(function () {

            var val1 = $(t.rows[i].cells[2]).find($('#gvCart_ctl' + i + '_lblComboGroup').text());

            i++;
        });
```

Comment: `$('#gvCart_ctl02_lblComboGroup').text()`

Comment: ^ That's only for a single row though, as that ID will change with additional rows. OP, what are you trying to do with the values? It's not clear if you need the loop, or all the values as an array, etc.

Comment: Adding some common classes server side would make this cleaner. Wouldn't need to be concatenating selectors like that

Comment: Add a css class and would make selection so much more easier.

Answer (score 1):

Due to ASP.Net being a bit finicky with it's generated client IDs, I usually try to stray from predicting or relying on their prefixes. Using classes would be much easier, but I'll provide a solution using either.

**Using IDs**

I'd suggest an "ends with" [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

If you just need to collect all of the values, you can get an array of them like so:

```
$("#gvCart tr span[id$=lblComboGroup]").map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get();
```

If you need to loop:

```
$("#gvCart tr:has(span[id$=lblComboGroup])").each(function() {
  let val = $(this).find("span[id$=lblComboGroup]").text();
  //do stuff
});
```

```js
console.log("Values as array:");
let result = $("#gvCart tr span[id$=lblComboGroup]")
  .map(function() { return $(this).text() })
  .get();
  
console.log(result);

// ----------------

console.log("Values in loop:");
$("#gvCart tr:has(span[id$=lblComboGroup])").each(function() {
  let val = $(this).find("span[id$=lblComboGroup]").text();
  console.log(val);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="gvCart">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Product</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblPromoPrice" style="font-weight:bold;">£187.62</span>
      </div>
      <div id="gvCart_ctl02_bundleQualifyForCombo">
        <div>
          <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboGroup" style="color:#E31837;font-size:2.5em;font-style:normal;">A</span>
        </div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboText" style="color:#0275C2;font-size:0.9em;font-style:normal;">5 Total From Group A Required</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblPromoPrice" style="font-weight:bold;">£187.62</span>
      </div>
      <div id="gvCart_ctl02_bundleQualifyForCombo">
        <div>
          <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboGroup" style="color:#E31837;font-size:2.5em;font-style:normal;">B</span>
        </div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboText" style="color:#0275C2;font-size:0.9em;font-style:normal;">5 Total From Group A Required</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblPromoPrice" style="font-weight:bold;">£187.62</span>
      </div>
      <div id="gvCart_ctl02_bundleQualifyForCombo">
        <div>
          <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboGroup" style="color:#E31837;font-size:2.5em;font-style:normal;">C</span>
        </div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboText" style="color:#0275C2;font-size:0.9em;font-style:normal;">5 Total From Group A Required</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

---

**Using classes:**

Add a class to your element:

```
<asp:Label CssClass="lblComboGroup"></asp:Label>
```

As array:

```
$("#gvCart tr span.lblComboGroup").map(function() { return $(this).text() }).get();
```

With loop / row context:

```
$("#gvCart tr:has(span.lblComboGroup)").each(function() {
  let val = $(this).find("span.lblComboGroup").text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

A jQuery Collection consists of every element that matches the selector. The most appropriate selectors are either `$('[id*=ComboGroup]')` or `$('[id$=ComboGroup]')` which translate as: *All elements with an id that has the word "ComboGroup"* or *All elements with an id that has the word "ComboGroup" at the end.* Once you got the selector it's only a matter of using the `.text()` method.

```js
console.log($('[id*=ComboGroup]').text());
```

```html
<table id="gvCart">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Product</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblPromoPrice" style="font-weight:bold;">£187.62</span>
      </div>
      <div id="gvCart_ctl02_bundleQualifyForCombo">
        <div>
          <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboGroup" style="color:#E31837;font-size:2.5em;font-style:normal;"></span>
        </div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl02_lblComboText" style="color:#0275C2;font-size:0.9em;font-style:normal;">5 Total From Group A Required</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Vlad</td>
    <td>Impaler</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl03_lblPromoPrice" style="font-weight:bold;">£699.99</span>
      </div>
      <div id="gvCart_ctl03_bundleQualifyForCombo">
        <div>
          <span id="gvCart_ctl03_lblComboGroup" style="color:#E31837;font-size:2.5em;font-style:normal;"></span>
        </div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl03_lblComboText" style="color:#0275C2;font-size:0.9em;font-style:normal;">5 Total From Group A Required</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Explosive</td>
    <td>Bomb</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl04_lblPromoPrice" style="font-weight:bold;">£26.59</span>
      </div>
      <div id="gvCart_ctl04_bundleQualifyForCombo">
        <div>
          <span id="gvCart_ctl04_lblComboGroup" style="color:#E31837;font-size:2.5em;font-style:normal;"></span>
        </div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl04_lblComboText" style="color:#0275C2;font-size:0.9em;font-style:normal;">5 Total From Group A Required</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Black</td>
    <td>Flag</td>
    <td>
      <div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl05_lblPromoPrice" style="font-weight:bold;">£298.00</span>
      </div>
      <div id="gvCart_ctl05_bundleQualifyForCombo">
        <div>
          <span id="gvCart_ctl05_lblComboGroup" style="color:#E31837;font-size:2.5em;font-style:normal;"></span>
        </div>
        <span id="gvCart_ctl05_lblComboText" style="color:#0275C2;font-size:0.9em;font-style:normal;">5 Total From Group A Required</span>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```